# Is the correct phrase 'never has so many people' or never have so many people'?

Tags: verbs

I can't see the logic in choosing one over the other. What I read in a news article was ' never has.... Thanks

Comment: You need to give the full quotation. It is possible to construct that sort of wording where *has/have* is referring to something other than *people*.  In this case, the word choice (*has/have*) will depend on the tense of the other thing, not people.  For instance, *this elevator never has so many people in it that that it would ever reasonably be expected to exceed its weight limit.*  In this sentence *has* refers to *elevator*.  Give the full quotation if you want a proper answer.

Answer (score 1):

"People" is plural, so you use "have".

Flip the sentence around, put has/have with its verb to see which version works:

Never ha?? so many people voted in the election.

So many people *has voted* in the election that... **<<< no**

So many people *have voted* in the election that... **<<< yes**

Answer (score 1):

The word *people* serves both as a plural for *person* and as the singular of *peoples;* in the latter sense, *a people* is

> a body of persons that are united by a common culture, tradition, or sense of kinship, that typically have common language, institutions, and beliefs, and that often constitute a politically organized group ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/people))

But the quantifier *so many* clearly  indicates that *people* is here being used as a plural, so that the appropriate verb form is *have.*

(Despite its following after rather than preceding that auxiliary verb, “so many people” is pretty clearly the subject of that verb. Compare Churchill’s “Never in the field of human conflict *was so much* owed by so many to so few.”)